# How do I prove that $T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n^{1.7}$ is $O(n^2)$ time complexity

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations, upper-lower-bounds

I wanted to prove that $T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n^{1.7} $  is   $O(n^2)$ time complexity using induction.
I start with induction step as $T(k) \le c\cdot k^2$ which gives me:
$$T(n/2) \le c\cdot (n/2)^2   $$
$$4T(n/2) \le 4c\cdot(n/2)^2  $$
$$4T(n/2) + n^{1.7} \le 4c\cdot (n/2)^2 + n^{1.7} $$
$$T(n) \le c\cdot n^2 + n^{1.7}  $$
$$T(n) \le c\cdot n^2 + n^2  $$
$$ T(n) \le (c+1)\cdot n^2 $$

Using $ T(n) \le (c+1)\cdot n^2 $ (that I got above) with $T(n) \le c\cdot n^2$ (that I will get from substituting $n$ in $T(k) \le c\cdot k^2$ ) I am not able to prove that $ T(n) \le(c+1)\cdot n^2 \le c\cdot n^2$
Hence its false to call it $O(n^2)$.

Can you help here solving this?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: @Gary formatted. thanks

Comment: Why do you get $(c+1)n^2\leq cn^2$?  It doesn't appear to follow from your work.

Comment: This is a compelling demonstration that the simplest possible approach doesn't work.  Therefore, in order to seek a good estimate, you need to give away less in some approximations.

Comment: @MichaelBurr updated my question to address that

Comment: @JBL I am not sure I follow

Comment: Try to show by induction that $T(n) \le cn^2 -\dfrac{n^{1.7}}{2^{0.3}-1}$.

Comment: @peterwhy how do I get that complex second term as a guess to start with.

Comment: Added an answer about the (non-complex) second term.

Comment: @JBL Can I ask how can one guess intuitively that the simplest approach might not work? Or is it just try and then try again

Comment: @user21130985: Starting out with the simplest possible thing is always a good idea.  Then if it doesn't work, one can look at what went wrong and try to diagnose how to tweak the simple approach to adjust for it.  (This is undoubtedly how the question-answerers here proceeded, except that you'd already done step 1 for them.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the original hypothesis $T(k) \le ck^2$ was not strong enough, you may try to introduce another term with less complexity to your hypotheses.

In this case, let $P(n)$ be the new proposition $T(n) \le cn^2 +c_2 n^{1.7}$, where $c_2$ is another constant to be determined. The additional $c_2n^{1.7}$ is inspired by the $n^{1.7}$ in the recurrence relation of $T(n)$.

Assume $P(k/2)$ is true, then for $n=k$,

$$\begin{align*}
T(k) &= 4T(k/2) +k^{1.7}\\
&\le 4\left[c(k/2)^2+c_2(k/2)^{1.7}\right] + k^{1.7}\\
&= ck^2 + 4c_2\frac{k^{1.7}}{2^{1.7}} + k^{1.7}\\
&= ck^2 + \left(2^{0.3}c_2+1\right)k^{1.7}\\
\end{align*}$$

At this point, if we pick $c_2$ such that $2^{0.3}c_2+1\le c_2$, then this would finish the proof:

$$\begin{align*}
2^{0.3}c_2 + 1 &\le c_2\\
\left(2^{0.3}-1\right) c_2 &\le -1\\
c_2 &\le -\frac{1}{2^{0.3}-1}
\end{align*}$$

In other words, it's possible to prove by induction that

$$T(n) \le cn^2 - \frac{n^{1.7}}{2^{0.3}-1}$$

or even (for example) $$T(n) \le cn^2 - 5n^{1.7}$$

for $n$ which is a power of $2$.

After proving that $T(n) \le cn^2 + c_2n^{1.7}$ for all $n$ that are powers of $2$ and for a fixed $c_2<0$, then it's also true that

$$T(n) \le cn^2 + c_2n^{1.7} \le cn^2.$$

Comment: Isn't the only way to prove $O(n^2)$ is to start with its actual form: $T(k) \le c\cdot k^2$

Comment: @user21130985 If you can prove $T(n) \le cn^2 - \dfrac{n^{1.7}}{2^{0.3}-1}$ for $n$ which is a power of $2$, then $T(n)$ is also $\le cn^2$ for those $n$s.

Comment: Makes sense. Though, it is tough to digest that the original hypothesis ($cn^2$) fails while a lower value ($cn^2 - 5n^{1.7}$) than the absolute max ($cn^2$) works. How is this possible?

Comment: @user21130985 My personal explanation: for the induction step, $T\left(\frac k2\right)\le c\left(\frac k2\right)^2 - 5\left(\frac k2\right)^{1.7}$ is a stronger assumption than just $T\left(\frac k2\right)\le c\left(\frac k2\right)^2$. Replacing $T\left(\frac k2\right)$ by $c\left(\frac k2\right)^2 - 5\left(\frac k2\right)^{1.7}$ is a smaller "jump", comparing with the jump from $T\left(\frac k2\right)$ to just $c\left(\frac k2\right)^2$. Even though the end goal $T(k)\le ck^2-5k^{1.7}$ is also a stronger statement to prove.

Comment: Nice. Got much clarity. Thanks!